# Spatial Pyramidal Pooling Layer

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am implementing a Spatial Pyramidal Pooling(SPP) layer which gives a fixed sized vector as an output. The code for this SPP layer is a part of a project that takes trains a model on variable sized images. Hence I put the input shape of my model as (None , None, 3) . The SPP layer takes its input tensor as an argument . According to the original paper of SPP , the window and stride size for the pooling layer is defined as follows :

```
window_height= ceil(input_tensor.shape[1]/pooling_level)
window_width= ceil(input_tensor.shape[2]/pooling_level)
stride_height=floor(input_tensor.shape[1]/pooling_level)
stride_width=floor(input_tensor.shape[2]/pooling_level)
```

But as I have taken the input shape to be (None , None, 3) hence I get an error telling that " **int** returned non-int (type NoneType) " .

Here is my code for the same:

```
def Pooling2D(input_tensor, pool_levels):
    pool_list=[]
    shape=input_tensor.shape
    for level in pool_levels:
        window_height=np.ceil(int(shape[1])/level)
        window_width=np.ceil(int(shape[2])/level)
        stride_height=np.floor(int(shape[1])/level)
        stride_width=np.floor(int(shape[2])/level)
        pooling=MaxPool2D(pool_size=(window_height,window_width),strides=(stride_height,stride_width))(input_tensor)
        flattened_tensor=K.flatten(pooling)
        pool_list.append(flattened_tensor)
    output_tensor=K.concatenate(pool_list,axis=-1)
    return(output_tensor)
```

Is there  any way around this error other than setting specific shapes to input images ?

Answer (score 0):

Rethink what you are trying to do here.

```
window_height= ceil(input_tensor.shape[1]/pooling_level)
```

You want to calculate the window width without telling the code what the actual image size is. So what your code does is actually

```
window_height= ceil(None/pooling_level)
```

I think you are a bit confused about what the SPP Layer does. 
The SPP Layer takes an image of arbitrary size as input and produces a 
output vector with a fixed length. This means even if you use the SPP layer 
you need to know the image width and height. This is not a drawback or something. The SPP Layer will accept any image size.

Comment: I get it . But the model that I am training should take in input images of Variable sizes . So I defined the input _shape as (None, None,3). But now if I specify a particular size to my inputs then my model is just going to accept input tensors of that particular shape and throw an error when it sees something different

Comment: Why do you set it to None? Can you programaticllay determine the image size and pass it for any image individually?

Comment: Thank know  you . I will surely try that out and let you know of the results. :)